# From scalaquery to Slick 3.1 - .list removed?

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to migrate from scalaquery to slick 3 but getting the following error when compiling:

```
Error:(107, 19) No matching Shape found.
Slick does not know how to map the given types.
Possible causes: T in Table[T] does not match your * projection. Or you use an unsupported type in a Query (e.g. scala List).
  Required level: slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel
     Source type: slick.lifted.ProvenShape[TestData]
   Unpacked type: T
     Packed type: G
        (for (test <- testTable)
                  ^
```

This is the related code befor the changes:

```
case class TestData(id: Int, test_double: Double)

object TestTable extends Table[TestData]("Test_Table") {
  var test_value = ""
  def id = column[Int]("ID_Test", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def nep_column = column[Double](test_value)
  def * = id ~ nep_column <> (TestData, TestData.unapply _)
}

def get_data = {
    db withSession {
            for (test <- testTable)
            yield test.*
          }.list
}
```

and this is after I changed it:

```
case class TestData(id: Int, test_double: Double)

class TestTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[TestData](tag, "Test_Table") {
  def id = column[Int]("ID_Test", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def nep_column = column[Double](test_value)
  def * = (id, nep_column) <> ((TestData.apply _).tupled, TestData.unapply)
}

object testTable extends TableQuery(new TestTable(_)) {
  var test_value = ""
}

def get_data = {
    Await.result(db.run(
        (for (test <- testTable)
          yield test.*).result), Duration.Inf)
}
```

So it doesn't seem to work with simply replacing `.list` with `.result`. And I can't find any references to `.list` in Slick 3 anymore. Was it removed?

Does anyone know what problem I have here and how to solve it?

Comment: I'm familiar with Slick 3+ only. I think you don't need `yield test.*`, but only `yield test`.

Comment: Basically, you build your select query as long as you need(joins, filters etc) and then you call `.result` when it's built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use for comprehension at all:

```
def get_data: Seq[TestData] = Await.result(db.run(testTable.result), Duration.Inf)
```